# Electron: Unable to load preload script: Resources/app.asar/src/preload.js

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron app that builds and runs in development, but when packaging the app with [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/), the preload script is not packaged in the right location.

This is a well documented issue and there are very similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66739463/electron-app-unable-to-load-preload-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60814430/electron-builder-with-browserwindow-and-preload-js-unable-to-load-preload-scrip) for example, but none of the replies or solutions are working in my case.

From my electron.js file:

```js
function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'src/preload.js'),
            contextIsolation: true,
        },
    });

    // In production, set the initial browser path to the local bundle generated
    // by the Create React App build process.
    // In development, set it to localhost to allow live/hot-reloading.
    const appURL = app.isPackaged
        ? url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true,
        })
        : 'http://localhost:3000';
    mainWindow.loadURL(appURL);

    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}
```

My preload script:

```js
const { contextBridge, shell } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'electron',
    {
        openBrowserWindow: (url) => shell.openExternal(url)
    }
)
```

And my Electron app package.json:

```json
    "build": {
        "extends": null,
        "appId": "com.app",
        "productName": "App",
        "directories": {
            "output": "dist"
        },
        "mac": {
            "target": {
                "target": "pkg",
                "arch": [
                    "universal"
                ]
            },
            "darkModeSupport": "true",
            "extendInfo": "app"
        },
        "pkg": {
            "installLocation": "/Applications",
            "overwriteAction": "upgrade"
        },
        "files": [
            "**",
            "../app/src/*",
            "src/preload.js"
        ],
        "extraResources": [
            "../app/src/*",
            "src/preload.js"
        ],
        "extraFiles": [
            "../app/src/*",
            "src/preload.js"
        ]
    }
```

Above I have tried to make sure the "src/preload.js" file is copied over in different ways, but I still get the error:

> Unable to load preload script: ...app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/preload.js
>
> Error: Cannot find module '...app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/preload.js'

The preload script is in fact copied over, but it is not part of the app.asar file. It is copied in to a src folder outside of the Resources folder which contains the app.asar file:

[image]

How do I correctly configure electron-builder so this file is in the right location and can be accessed at package runtime?

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.resolve(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js'),
        contextIsolation: true,
    },
});
```

Does it works ? (worked for me with electron-webpack and electron-builder)

Answer (score 2):

```
        preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'src/preload.js'),
```

As you are not packaging the `preload.js` into the app package file (asar default), this won't work like this. `app.getAppPath()` will indicate the app package file(or directory, in case you are setting `asar` as false)

Your code is indicating `/xxx.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/preload.js` or `/xxx.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/preload.js`
Your preload script file is not there but in the 2nd parent's directory.

So here is the correct path in your case,

```
path.join(app.getAppPath(), '..', '..', 'src', 'preload.js');
```

Comment: will this command copy the node_modules folder into the resources folder? Second will the paths break if I have development paths?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76397570/expected-app-structure-and-pathing-problems-after-build-of-electron-project-usin

Comment: I'm not sure yet but if you wanna pack some specific `node_moduels` please have a look at `extraResources` https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents.html#extraresources

Comment: if i have a path of `project/binaries` in dev which is packed into `resources/binaries` will the paths of my electron files change in the build. second, if i add the `binaries` folder in the `extraResources` setting will it be copied all automatically into the resources folder? Is the extra resources have the `binaries` folder in it or will it be there in the `asar`?

Comment: It won't copy your `binaries` folder into `asar`. I'd suggest you pack the app and try to have a look inside the packed app. It will make much more sense

Comment: say i pack the app manually copying `binaries` folder into the resources folder like `resources/binaries` then what will the pathing be in such a case. if i put the `binaries` folder in the main `app` folder then i think the `app.getAppPath()` should work I presume?

Comment: Yes, it will work

Answer (score 2):

First, add console logs for testing.

```
console.log({dirname: __dirname})
console.log({getAppPath: app.getAppPath()})
console.log({resourcesPath: process.resourcesPath})

const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ ... })
```

Second, you have to add `contextIsolation: true`.

If you are using `electron-builder` and for some reason you cannot add `contextIsolation: true`  you can use this workaround:

package.json

```
  "build": {
    ...
    "extraResources": [
      ...
      "app/preload.js" // <---- add your path
    ],
  }
```

electron.js

```
const preloadPath =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? path.join(__dirname, '../preload.js') // <---- add your path
        : path.join(process.resourcesPath, '/app/preload.js'); // <---- add your path

const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      ...
      webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: false,
        preload: preloadPath,
        ...
      }
})
```

What is `path.join(process.resourcesPath, '/app/preload.js')` ?

After building your app you can find your extra resources here

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\<app>\resources` - for `Windows`.

For `MacOS` you can `right click` on your app and click on `Show Package Contents` > `Resources`

Answer (score 1):

I [solved this problem](https://github.com/simonw/datasette-app/commit/f0449f28f3d82c90dbb18b23b8b37d23fd663a84) by adding `"preload.js"` directly to the `build -> files` list in my `package.json` - I don't know why that was necessary since it already had `"*.json"` in it but it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: let me try this.